# JAX-WS Client can't connect after redeployment (NullPointerException in SymbolTable)

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

When we redeploy our webapplication with an jax-ws client, the client can not connect to the webservice. While connecting to the server it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.ctc.wstx.util.SymbolTable.findSymbol(SymbolTable.java:385) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseLocalName(StreamScanner.java:1833) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:2963) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2907) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleRootElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2049) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2029) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1100) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:81) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:78) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:99) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:89) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.hasWSDLDefinitions(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:120) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:256) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:219) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:167) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77) ~[na:1.7.0-ea]
```

After restarting TomCat the client could successfully connect to the sever again.
(Tested with JDK 6 and JDK 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll use spring-ws instead, tested with redeploying without a problem.