# JAX-WS client fails after redployment via tomcat manager

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

I have an application acting as a client to a JAX-WS server. The connection works fine if I deploy the application directly by placing the war into the tomcat `webapps` directory (even if doing a hot deploy). However if I undeploy, then redeploy the application using the tomcat manager (from an automated script) I get the exception below thrown anytime it attempts to establish a connection.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ctc.wstx.util.SymbolTable.copyArrays(SymbolTable.java:574)
        at com.ctc.wstx.util.SymbolTable.findSymbol(SymbolTable.java:403)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseLocalName(StreamScanner.java:1770)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2914)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleRootElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2093)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2073)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.hasWSDLDefinitions(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
        [... continues into application specific code calling the service ...]
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566732/jax-ws-client-cant-connect-after-redeployment-nullpointerexception-in-symbolta) showed up here in a search with someone having a similar problem, but had no resolution other than to use spring-ws which isn't really an option for me at the moment.

Has anyone run into this before and been able to resolve the issue? I'm a bit puzzled by what is going on here to make deployment via the tomcat manager different than deploying by placing the files in `webapps`.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue.  The problem was that I had a dependency on cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.5.2.jar in my classpath, which contains an implementation of org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl that conflicts with the same class in rt.jar that comes with the JDK.

Later versions of cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws no longer contain this class.  After upgrading to  cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.6.15.jar,  the problem was resolved.

I expect that the problem occurs intermittently because the classloader would randomly choose which implementation of ProviderImpl to use each time the WAR is deployed.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the problem was on SymbolTable class, which was both on com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SymbolTable (from rt.jar) and com.ctc.wstx.util.SymbolTable (from wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar). After removing wstx-asl lib from my classpath we made redeployment via tomcat manager with no errors.